# how can i identify a process

Tags: c, process

"Write a single program, called program.c, that will create a total of 9 processes which will identify themselves as process0, process1, process2, process3, process4, process5, process6, process7 and process8. The original process should be process0."

How can I have my process identify as "processX" when creating a process using fork just returns a PID of 0 to the child, and some number to the parent?  I thought the PID was the identifier.

Comment: PID is the unique identifier for a process. By "identify", what is your intention, printing it out or storing it somewhere, etc,?

Comment: I really don't have any intention at this point.  I am just trying to understand the assignment statement.  How can I have a process identify itself specificlly as "process#" (0-8), if the only way to get the identity of a process is to access its PID?

Comment: If you intend to change the process names and want the child processes to know the same then, store the PID to process-name mapping in a shared table with read access to the child processes. If you do not intend to change the process name then, pass it as an argument during exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        exit(1);
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Process%d\n", i);
        exit(0);
    }
}
printf("Process%d\n", 0);
```

Comment: Oh so I just explicitly create this identifier... so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *getpid()* if you use Unix to get PID of current process:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t getpid(void);
```

Comment: Well, if you need to print it like process0..8, then you can print "process0" in parent process and *"process" <concat> getpid() - getppid()*. This values is not guaranteed to be consequent, because other processes can born in the same time. Another solution can involve *getpgid()* call.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Linux, you can change the process name by altering `argv[0]`.  When you compile program.c, name the executable file `process0`.  The forked processes can each `strcpy()` a new name into `argv[0]`, as long as the new name does not exceed the size of the original name.  (Keeping track of which process gets which name is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: That's really interesting. It's nice to know that this is possible.